# NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler is not workling with background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler command does not work with background worker.Event is as :

```
void MainWindowsViewModel_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    StrokesEllipse = ((StrokeCollection)sender);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        StrokesEllipse.Save(memoryStream);
        //convert memory stream to  array
        EllipseDrawing = memoryStream.ToArray();
        //save the above array to say - database
        }
    }
```

And we declared event on constructor  as below

```
_strokesEllipse = new StrokeCollection();
(_strokesEllipse as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(MainWindowsViewModel_CollectionChanged);
```

And we are binding stoke collection on the background worker completed event. as Below

```
string s = GetMechanicSignature();
if (s != "")
{
    EllipseDrawing = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
}
if (EllipseDrawing != null)
{
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(EllipseDrawing))
        {
            _strokesEllipse = new StrokeCollection(memoryStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

}
```

inkcanvas control does not showing loaded data. why? When we try without  background worker then inkcanvas control loading the data very well? 
inkcanvas xml is as below

```
<InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanVas" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="{Binding VCRSignatureModel.IsEnable,Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White"  Width="700" Height="90" Margin="40,0,0,0" Strokes="{Binding StrokesEllipse,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes>
        <DrawingAttributes Color = "Black" Width = "6" />
    </InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes>
</InkCanvas>
```

Comment: Cross-thread operations are not allowed. I guess that is the issue.

Comment: You need to use Dispatcher.Invoke to run code on the UI thread.

Comment: can you provide exact solution how to  call by  Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: @Patrick Hofman no any error showing

Comment: @PatrickHofman  Shouldn't be cross threaded, OP said it was fired on the completed event code which should be marshalled back to the UI thread.

Comment: I see no evidence of that in the code. @BobVale

Comment: @PatrickHofman I Quote "And we are binding stoke collection on the background worker completed event. as Below"

Comment: That doesn't mean `CollectionChanged` is called on the UI thread @BobVale

Comment: @PatrickHofman Why not, the collection would be modified on the UI thread as so the changed event should also fire there?  OP is not getting an exception, which they would if it was a cross thread, they are getting nothing happening.  the real problem is they are not modifying the collection, simply replacing the field with a new collection.

Comment: That is a good possiblity, yes @BobVale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not modifying the collection, you are replacing it. As your background work completed event should be firing in the UI thread it is not a threading issue.

The quickest way to fix this would be to add the following line after the line `_strokesEllipse = new StrokeCollection(memoryStream);` in your worker completed code.

```
MainWindowsViewModel_CollectionChanged(
   _strokesEllipse,
   new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace);
```

Alternatively you could change the code to read:

```
try
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(EllipseDrawing))
    {
        var newCollection = new StrokeCollection(memoryStream);
        _strokesEllipse.Clear();
        _strokesEllipse.Add(newCollection);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
```